# Returning a value from an if-statement in Prolog

Tags: if-statement, prolog, return, operator-keyword, relational

I'm trying to write a simple code like this:

In pseudo code:

```
function(x,y):
if y = 0:
        return x
if x = 0:
        return y
```

I'm guess I'm supposed to use sth like

```
function(X,Y,Return) :-
```

as a starting point and "if y = 0:" would be

```
y =:= 0.
```

but how do I return X? I need to assign it to the Return variable, but how?

Edit: I think I've found it:

```
test(X,Y,Z) :- 
    ( Y =:= 0 ->  Z = X );
    ( X =:= 0 ->  Z = Y ).
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
function(X, 0, X).
function(0, Y, Y).
```

---

In response to the edit. The above solution is better, because it's simpler than

```
function(X,Y,Z) :- 
    ( Y =:= 0 ->  Z = X );
    ( X =:= 0 ->  Z = Y ).
```

and can be used backwards:

```
function(0, X, 3).
```

finds `X` in one version, but not the other.

Comment: @HaiseSasaki That doesn't work correctly: `function(1, 0, Return).` -> `false`.

Comment: I'm confused to what this means. What is exactly false?

Comment: @HaiseSasaki SWI-Prolog's response. Other prologs might say "No" instead.